# Rails: How to know in advance if "save" is going to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Consider this code of my Controller:

```
def create
  change_some_db_values
  buyer = Buyer.new(params[:buyer])
  if buyer.save
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    render('new')
  end
end
```

I would like to know in advance if `buyer.save` will fail or not. If it's gonna fail I don't want to execute `change_some_db_values`. How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [add a check for validity before saving](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#valid-and-invalid):

```
def create
  buyer = Buyer.new(params[:buyer])
  if buyer.valid?
    change_some_db_values
  end
  if buyer.save
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    render('new')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

A better way might be to put all the changes into a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) and then rollback if `save` fails.

```
def create
  Buyer.transaction do
    change_some_db_values
    buyer = Buyer.new(params[:buyer])
    buyer.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually - I quite like this solution, it doesnt have the extra validity check pre save, however, the change_some_db_values needs to come out of that transaction and only be run if buyer.new_record? with an additional save afterwards

Comment: @omar I assume that those `change_some_db_values` happens in the same database. So if `buyer.save!` fails, the entire transaction will roll back, including whatever those changes were.

Comment: Ah - sorry, had misread the question - had assumed he wanted to run `change_some_db_values` IF the save failed - not always.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `valid?` function to see if the object is valid for operations. Here is sample code that implements this approach:

```
def create
  # change_some_db_values
  buyer = Buyer.new(params[:buyer])
  if buyer.valid?
    change_some_db_values
  end
  if buyer.save
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  else
    render('new')
  end
end
```